# Showing the range of this PDO is dense.

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Consider the PDO; $Q:=-p(x)\frac{d^2}{dx^2}-p'(x)\frac{d}{dx}+q(x)+1$, an unbounded operator on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ densely defined on compactly supported infinitely differentiable functions $C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ where $p\in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ is positive, $q\in C(\mathbb{R})$ is nonnegative.

I'd like to show that the range of $Q$ is dense in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. One route, that hasn't proven fruitful, is to show that $Q^*$ is injective, where $Q^*$ is the adjoint of $Q$ defined on $\{u\in L^2: Qu\in L^2\}$. In this case, if $Q^*u=0$, then

$\frac{d}{dx}[p(x)u'(x)]=p(x)u''(x)+p'(x)u'(x)=(1+q(x))u(x)$

where to go from here, or whether this is the correct direction to proceed in, is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Multiplying your last equation with $u(x)$, integrating over $x$ and using integration by parts on the lhs yields
$$-\int p \, (u')^2 \, \mathrm{d}x = \int (1+q) \, u^2 \, \mathrm{d}x.$$
Hence, $u = 0$.